# Share data between client with server-sent event

Tags: javascript, php, session, server-sent-events

I would like to build a web page where users can draw simultaneously on the same canvas. Drawing and communication with the server works fine. Now, I would like to synchronise the clients, i.e. update each client with the last drawing from the others.

My initial idea was to use server-sent event, therefore ... I realised that each client run is own PHP script with its own session. I can't figure out - on server side - how to share data from one client to another without storing data in a database.

I wonder if SSE is the right choice. Any help is welcome.

Comment: you can use node/sockiet.io for it cuz its run on runtime you can make a hit when a user draw something with the draw data and the hit will go on to every client browser symontenously. like real time noification

Comment: if you want i can share you a repositry code of real time notification system built on codeigniter 3+node+sockiet .io

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan Yes, I'm also using codeigniter 3 ! How do we proceed ? I post my email here ?

Comment: https://github.com/xunaidahmed/realtime-notification-codeigniter